# Default controller for extension cannot be determined

Tags: typo3, extbase, typo3-8.x

Being my TYPO3 extension called "my_content", I wanna create a plugin that lists a bunch of personas.

web/typo3conf/ext/my_content/Configuration/TSconfig/ContentElements/persona.tsconfig:

```
mod.wizards.newContentElement.wizardItems.plugins {
    elements {
        persona {
            iconIdentifier = tx-mask-persona
            title = LLL:EXT:my_content/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:tx_mycontent_domain_model_persona
            description = LLL:EXT:my_content/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:tx_mycontent_domain_model_persona.description
            tt_content_defValues {
                CType = list
                list_type = mycontent_persona
            }
        }
    }
    show := addToList(persona)
}
```

web/typo3conf/ext/my_content/Configuration/TCA/Overrides/tt_content.php:

```
\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::registerPlugin(
    'Vendor.my_content',
    'Persona',
    'Personas'
);
```

web/typo3conf/ext/my_content/ext_localconf.php:

```
\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::configurePlugin(
    'Vendor.my_content',
    'Persona',
    [
        'Persona' => 'list'
    ],
    // non-cacheable actions
    [
        'Persona' => 'list'
    ]
);
```

I receive the error below:

```
Oops, an error occurred!
The default controller for extension "MyContent" and plugin "Persona" can not be determined. Please check for 
TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::configurePlugin() in your ext_localconf.php.
```

Is all the naming of plugins, vendor, etc, right?
Is there something I'm doing wrong?
Using TYPO3 8.7.18.

Comment: Have a look in TypoScript Object Browser, there probably the plugin is defined as `plugin.tx_mycontent_persona`, it's possible that the `list_type` in the table `tt_content` is then `tx_mycontent_persona` instead of `mycontent_persona`.

Comment: Check my answer, @David

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the camelcase type in `registerPlugin()` and `configurePlugin()` for your extension name, so don't use `my_content`, it's `MyContent` in this case.

Comment: Thanks for your help, Thomas. That was it. Weird, because I tried that before, but didn't work. Maybe I didn't clear the cache properly.

Comment: In such default cases look into working extensions. The extension "News" has many best practices in the code.

Comment: Yeah, I looked that one first, but "news" has no underscore "_".

Comment: Ah, right. :) Can you flag my answer as the most useful one? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

My TypoScript looks fine:

```
tt_content.list.20 {
    mycontent_persona = USER 
    userFunc = TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Core\Bootstrap->run
    extensionName = MyContent
    pluginName = Persona
    vendorName = Vendor
}
```

And my list_type plugin is "mycontent_persona".

I don't really know what's wrong with the plugin. All seems fine.
Cache is cleared as well.

Comment: so how your plugin is registered in TypoScript with `plugin. ... `?